# How to modify symfony crud

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

So I have been trying for some time now to modify symfonys basic crud system to my needs. However I am failing to understand why in the get form they define the entity and then in the post they over write the entity again?

I have a relationship that relates 1 Job to Many Work items, what I wanted to modify was the create 'Work' so that it was created from a job item, and the jobId was passed via the dash_work_new route.

**Option 1**

What I managed was to load my job entity from the passed variable and set my work item, like so $entity->setWorkJob(). Great? No because on submit the dash_work_create route is called and why? is the work entity yet again defined? therefore wiping anything I set in the newAction() method

**Option 2**

So I thought I would pass the variable as a hidden field then load up all the data on submit, but hang on the createCreateForm is redefined in the createAction as well, so if I tried to pass a variable via the createCreateForm($entity,$jobId) in the new action. I would also need to define it in the createAction, but I don't have the ....  AH %#@@ EXPLETIVE EXPLETIVE EXPLETIVE

AH the frustration and lack of understanding. For reference the symfony workController generated by console crud. I left in the changed new route that went from @route new to @route new/{jobId}

Your help will very much appreciated

```
/**
 * Creates a new Work entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="dash_work_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("LaelapsInvoiceBundle:Work:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Work();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('dash_job'));

    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Creates a form to create a Work entity.
 *
 * @param Work $entity The entity
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createCreateForm(Work $entity)
{

    $form = $this->createForm(new WorkType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('dash_work_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    return $form;
}

/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Work entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new/{jobId}", name="dash_work_new")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction($jobId)
{

    $entity = new Work();

    $form  = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

Comment: "dash_work_create route is called and why?" - you set form action to that route, that's why.

Comment: I realise that malcolm, this is the default behaviour of the controller when it is created with php app/console doctrine:generate:crud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your POST action the form skeleton is created:

```
$entity = new Work();
$form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
```

Because it's needed for handle request, then later form is filled with request data:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Now you have your form with data you provided in `newAction()`, and later you validate it:

```
$form->isValid()
```

Now, enough theory. I see that you just want to pass `jobId` to your POST action. The simplest way is by url, all you have to do is change the route and action of form. The POST action can looks like this:

```
/**
 * Creates a new Work entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{jobId}", name="dash_work_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("LaelapsInvoiceBundle:Work:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request, $jobId)
{
    $entity = new Work();
    $form = $this->createForm(new WorkType(), $entity);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    //fetch you Job entity by $jobId and do what you need.

    $job = $em->getRepository('MyBundle\Entity\Job')->findOneById($jobId);
    $entity->setWorkJob($job);

    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('dash_job'));

}

return array(
    'entity' => $entity,
    'form'   => $form->createView(),
);
```

And new action:

```
/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Work entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new/{jobId}", name="dash_work_new")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction($jobId)
{

    $entity = new Work();

    $form = $this->createForm(new WorkType(), $entity,
                array(
                    'action' => $this->generateUrl('dash_work_create', array('jobId' => $jobId ))
             ));

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```